# Add to homescreen on chrome - Icon not getting downloaded on the phone

Tags: html, google-chrome, meta-tags, homescreen

All the meta information have been added according to the doc's given in [chrome-developers site](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/installtohomescreen).

But the **Add to homescreen** is not working on chrome mobile browser -- **The ICON given** is not getting saved on the phone. The app's icon is taking some random screenshot of the page.

The site that I'm working on - [here](http://inkl.co)

Here's the code -->

```
// for chrome
<meta content="yes" name="mobile-web-app-capable" />
<link href="/images/inkl-196.png" rel="shortcut icon" sizes="196x196" />
<link href="/images/inkl-128.png" rel="shortcut icon" sizes="128x128" />
// for safari
<link href="/images/touch-icon-iphone-default.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
<link href="/images/touch-icon-ipad.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" />
<link href="/images/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" />
<link href="/images/touch-icon-ipad-retina.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" />
```

Please comments on where I might have gone wrong.

Not sure why, tried other solutions online - dint help.

Comment: Sorry, added -- any more info, will provide

Comment: Downvoter, please check on the updated question.

Comment: @rene, thought it makes more sense to give a live code. Anyhow, added the code as well. please check

Comment: Doesnt help. Any other inputs anyone?

Comment: No activity for this question?.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we had an issue with our docs where we recommended 196px and in fact it should have been 192px - this might explain the issue.

Secondly, now (Dec 2015) the recommended solution is to use the [web app manifest](http://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/).  The Web App manifest describes what the browser should launch and how it should launch it from the homescreen.  You will need to create a manifest file (see below) and link to it from your pages with `<link rel="manifest" href="{url to your manifest}">` in the `head` of your html page.

Example (launches the index page fullscreen):

```
{
  "short_name": "Kinlan's Amaze App",
  "name": "Kinlan's Amazing Application ++",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-2x.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-3x.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-4x.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "landscape"
}
```